# iOS: UIActivityIndicator in navigation bar not stopping

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsthread, uiactivityindicatorview

I wrote small test app, that doesn't work. This is my storyboard:
[image: storyboard]
<sub>(source: [cs618122.vk.me](http://cs618122.vk.me/v618122477/dc8d/Z9DffvZC3RY.jpg))</sub>

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIActivityIndicatorView* ai = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    UIBarButtonItem* rightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:ai];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
    [ai startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 5];
        NSLog(@"STOP!");
        [ai stopAnimating];
    });
}
```

This is work result:
[image: work result]
<sub>(source: [cs618122.vk.me](http://cs618122.vk.me/v618122477/dc84/Wim1wkPYnEw.jpg))</sub>

What's wrong?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is kind of the same problem solved:

```
[spinner startAnimating];
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    // ... do other stuff in the background
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [spinner stopAnimating];
   });
});
```

[UIActivityIndicatorView won't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14538560/uiactivityindicatorview-wont-stop)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try?

> ```
> dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>     [ai stopAnimating];
> });
> ```

Answer (score 1):

All userinterface updates must be run on the main thread (mainQueue):

```
 [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
        [ai stopAnimating];
    }];
```

Comment: While this can resolve the issue, you don't explain why or handle the original delay...

Answer (score 1):

All UI updates must be run on the main thread, and you're running the stop on a background thread.

Also, don't start a background thread and then sleep it. Use a different API to run your delayed function, like a timer or `dispatch_after` (which you can add to the main queue and solve both problems).

Comment: Why the people doesn't like this answer while others got upVoted, **Do they just wants in the exact output (code)**, while this gives all the info which others wrote in the coding way.